# Split first column of data based on comma, add new row and duplicate remaining columns

Tags: perl, excel

I encounter this problem frequently in Excel.  VBA seems to blow up when you hit too many rows or if you have too many items in the first cell.  I think it would be easier to do this with Perl from now on.

Data in form:

```
1,2,3 Apples Smith
8 Orange Dog
```

Want data in form:

```
1 Apples Smith
2 Apples Smith
3 Apples Smith
8 Orange Dog
...
```

I get the structure... but not all the syntax

```
$MYFILE = "mydata.txt";
open(MYFILE) or die("Could not open file.");
foreach $line (<MYFILE>) {
```

Assume the split column is always first.  Other columns delimited by space or tab.

Can someone provide a Perl script example that will do this?

Comment: Look up the perl commands `split` and `join`.  That should do everything you want.

Comment: This is a really simple awk task: `awk '{l = split($1,b,","); $1=""; for(i=1; i <= l; ++i) print b[i] $0}' mydata.txt`

Comment: And please **NEVER** use a single Argument `open` in Perl!! Always use the 3 Statement open. Its safer and more readable. eg.: `open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Cannot open $file for reading";`

Comment: Thanks Nirk, that worked great! I guess I need to learn awk.

Comment: @user2632674 there is a perl way to do it, but it is longer (even if you use `-lane`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $MYFILE = "mydata.txt";

# this is the correct syntax for open. $! is the system error
open( my $in, '<', $MYFILE) or die "Could not open file: $!"; 

while( my $line= <$in>)
  { my( $nbs, $data)= split /\s/, $line, 2; # separate numbers from data
    my @nbs= split /,/, $nbs;               # get the list of numbers
    foreach my $nb (@nbs)                   # output each number and data
      { print "$nb $data"; }
  }
```